# More problems with dependently typed programming in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

I'm working in an example of dependently typed program in Haskell and I would like to "rewrite" an evidence of propositional equality type `a :~: b` defined in [singletons](https://github.com/goldfirere/singletons/blob/master/README.md) library.

More specifically, I have a data type for represent evidence of regular expression membership. My trouble is how to deal with evidence of concatenation of two regular expressions. In my code, I have a GADT called `InRegExp xs e` that express the fact that `xs` is in the language of regular expression `e`. For concatenation, I have the following constructor:

```
    InCat :: InRegExp xs l -> InRegExp ys r   ->
         (zs :~: xs ++ ys) -> InRegExp zs (Cat l r)
```

So far, so good. Now I want to define an inversion lemma for membership in concatenation of two regular expressions:

```
inCatInv :: InRegExp (xs ++ ys) (Cat e e') -> (InRegExp xs e , InRegExp ys e')
inCatInv (InCat p p' Refl) = (p , p')
```

but the code is rejected by GHC with the following error message:

```
Could not deduce (xs1 ~ xs)
   from the context ('Cat e e' ~ 'Cat l r)
      bound by a pattern with constructor
             InCat :: forall (zs :: [Nat])
                             (xs :: [Nat])
                             (l :: RegExp [Nat])
                             (ys :: [Nat])
                             (r :: RegExp [Nat]).
                      InRegExp xs l
                      -> InRegExp ys r -> zs :~: (xs ++ ys) -> InRegExp zs ('Cat l r),
           in an equation for ‘inCatInv’
  at /Users/rodrigo/Dropbox/projects/haskell/experiments/src/Lib.hs:44:11-25
or from ((xs ++ ys) ~ (xs1 ++ ys1))
  bound by a pattern with constructor
             Refl :: forall (k :: BOX) (b :: k). b :~: b,
           in an equation for ‘inCatInv’
  at /Users/rodrigo/Dropbox/projects/haskell/experiments/src/Lib.hs:44:22-25
  ‘xs1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a pattern with constructor
          InCat :: forall (zs :: [Nat])
                          (xs :: [Nat])
                          (l :: RegExp [Nat])
                          (ys :: [Nat])
                          (r :: RegExp [Nat]).
                   InRegExp xs l
                   -> InRegExp ys r -> zs :~: (xs ++ ys) -> InRegExp zs ('Cat l r),
        in an equation for ‘inCatInv’
        at /Users/rodrigo/Dropbox/projects/haskell/experiments/src/Lib.hs:44:11
  ‘xs’ is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for
         inCatInv :: InRegExp (xs ++ ys) ('Cat e e')
                     -> (InRegExp xs e, InRegExp ys e')
       at /Users/rodrigo/Dropbox/projects/haskell/experiments/src/Lib.hs:43:13
Expected type: InRegExp xs e
  Actual type: InRegExp xs1 l
Relevant bindings include
  p :: InRegExp xs1 l
    (bound at /Users/rodrigo/Dropbox/projects/haskell/experiments/src/Lib.hs:44:17)
  inCatInv :: InRegExp (xs ++ ys) ('Cat e e')
              -> (InRegExp xs e, InRegExp ys e')
    (bound at /Users/rodrigo/Dropbox/projects/haskell/experiments/src/Lib.hs:44:1)
In the expression: p
In the expression: (p, p')
```

In Agda or Idris, this kind of inversion lemma works just fine. Is possible to express such inversion lemma in Haskell? The complete code is available in the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/rodrigogribeiro/9be413e5b59d87812f3c8eaae2dc2dcc).

Any tip or explanation of how can I express such lemma or why it isn't possible to express is highly appreciated.

Comment: The problem you are having is non-injective type families. Unfortunately there is no real easy way around this. Essentially you have `(xs ++ ys) ~ (xs' ++ ys')` - remember that the `xs` and `ys` inside the constructor are existentially quantified, so they give rise to new type variables - from which the compiler is unable to deduce that `xs ~ xs'` and `ys ~ ys'`. Instead of using propositional equality, you'll need to have an inductive proof that `xs ++ ys = zs` - I'm guessing that `inCatInv` will have to be recursive as well.

Comment: This looks fundamentally impossible: at the type level, `[] ++ [x]` is indistinguishable from `[x] ++ []`, and so the type of `inCatInv` is inherently ambiguous. More precisely, whoever _calls_ `inCatInv` gets to choose `xs,ys`, with the only constraint that `xs++ys` is the same list as in the `InRegExp` type. So, the `inCatInv` type is promising to the _caller_ that it can split `zs` into any possible way as `xs++ys` (caller's choice), which is not what it really does (nor what it is intended to do, AFAICS).

Comment: Your lemma doesn't seem true. `InRegexp ("ab" ++ "c") (Cat "a" "bc")` doesn't imply `InRegexp "ab" "a"`.

Comment: @user2407038: In order to have an inductive proof of `xs ++ ys = zs`, I'll need to recurse over the structure of `xs`, using a singleton `SList xs`, right? Or there's other way to do this?

Comment: @RodrigoRibeiro Yes, that is correct - you'll need a list singleton. You could of course postulate that it is correct with `unsafeCoerce` which would not required a `SList` (just a `Proxy`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method for writing dependently typed programs in Haskell is to first write it in Agda, then replace `(x : A) -> B` with `Sing x -> b`. However, we can use `Proxy` instead of `Sing` when we're sure we won't need to compute with values.

In our case (assuming our goal is to write `hasEmpty` from your gist), we only need a single `Sing` in the `Cat` constructor, because we need a pattern matching proof for the following function:

```
appendEmpty :: Sing xs -> Proxy ys -> (xs :++ ys) :~: '[] -> (xs :~: '[], ys :~: '[])
appendEmpty SNil         ys eq = (Refl, eq)
appendEmpty (SCons x xs) ys eq = case eq of {}
```

`appendEmpty` establishes that the sublists of the empty list are empty too, so we can use them in the `Cat` case for `hasEmpty`. Anyway, below's the whole code.

I used a slightly different but equivalent definition for `Star` that reuses `Choice` and `Eps` for building a list structure.

```
{-# language
  TemplateHaskell, UndecidableInstances, LambdaCase, EmptyCase,
  DataKinds, PolyKinds, GADTs, TypeFamilies, ScopedTypeVariables,
  TypeOperators #-}

import Data.Singletons.Prelude
import Data.Singletons.TH
import Data.Proxy

$(singletons [d|
  data Regex c
    = Sym c
    | Cat (Regex c) (Regex c)
    | Choice (Regex c) (Regex c)
    | Star (Regex c)
    | Eps
    deriving (Show)
 |])

appendEmpty :: Sing xs -> Proxy ys -> (xs :++ ys) :~: '[] -> (xs :~: '[], ys :~: '[])
appendEmpty SNil         ys eq = (Refl, eq)
appendEmpty (SCons x xs) ys eq = case eq of {} 

data InRegex :: [c] -> Regex c -> * where
  InEps   :: InRegex '[] Eps
  InSym   :: InRegex '[c] (Sym c)
  InCat   :: Sing xs -> InRegex xs l -> InRegex ys r -> InRegex (xs :++ ys) (Cat l r)
  InLeft  :: InRegex xs l -> InRegex xs (Choice l r)
  InRight :: InRegex ys r -> InRegex ys (Choice l r)
  InStar  :: InRegex xs (Choice Eps (Cat r (Star r))) -> InRegex xs (Star r)

hasEmpty :: Sing r -> Either (InRegex '[] r) (InRegex '[] r -> Void)
hasEmpty (SSym _)   = Right (\case {})
hasEmpty (SCat l r) = case hasEmpty l of
  Left inl -> case hasEmpty r of
    Left  inr -> Left (InCat SNil inl inr)
    Right notInr -> Right
      (\(InCat xs inl (inr :: InRegex ys r)) -> case appendEmpty xs (Proxy :: Proxy ys) Refl of
          (Refl, Refl) -> notInr inr)
  Right notInl -> Right
    (\(InCat xs inl (inr :: InRegex ys r)) -> case appendEmpty xs (Proxy :: Proxy ys) Refl of
        (Refl, Refl) -> notInl inl)
hasEmpty (SChoice l r) = case hasEmpty l of
  Left inl     -> Left (InLeft inl)
  Right notInl -> case hasEmpty r of
    Left inr     -> Left (InRight inr)
    Right notInr -> Right (\case
      InLeft  inl -> notInl inl
      InRight inr -> notInr inr)
hasEmpty (SStar r) = Left (InStar (InLeft InEps))
hasEmpty SEps = Left InEps
```